# How to retrieve values from Oracle in an Excel file

Tags: excel, oracle

I have an Excel file that has an employee_ID column with 100000 (100K) rows, 
I have an employee table in an oracle DB that has 5000000 (5 million) rows, the table contains 2 columns : employee_ID and employee_name.

What is the most efficient way to add the Employee_name column in the excel file ? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it quickly without trying to automate reading the excel values into the database then:

In the excel file add a column:

```
="SELECT employee_name FROM employee WHERE employee_id = "&A1&" UNION ALL"
```

(Assuming the employee ids start in cell `A1` and go down the rows).

Then:

- copy-paste the above formula down for each of the rows containing employee ids.
- Select the SQL you've just generated for 100,000 rows and copy-paste this into a text file.
- Replace the `UNION ALL` on the last line with a semi-colon `;`
- Save the file.
- Run the file in SQL/Plus or SQL/Developer (or another IDE) and spool/redirect the output to a file.
- Copy/paste the data you generated from the database back into Excel.
- Delete the column you used to generate the SQL.

To keep the values in order you could use:

```
="SELECT "&ROW()&" AS rn, employee_name FROM employee WHERE employee_id = "&A1&" UNION ALL"
```

Then add this line before it:

```
SELECT employee_name FROM (
```

and at the end, replace the final `UNION ALL` with:

```
) ORDER BY rn;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, using this method, will i be sure that oracle will keep the same order ?

Comment: It should and you can always generate a few sample names by hand to check it. If you are using parallelised queries then it might be different and there are techniques you can use to get round that - I'll add an update in a couple of hours.

Comment: Better: `"SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID="&A1&" UNION ALL"`. This will generate a result set with both `EMPLOYEE_ID` and `EMPLOYEE_NAME` so you don't have to worry about the correspondence between ID and name. Then just replace all the rows in your spreadsheet with the results of the query. Best of luck.

Comment: thank you Bob nice idea ! but what i didn't mention was that there are (many) other columns in the excel file besides the ID column.. and they are not all from the same table..

Answer (score 0):

You can pull 5 million records from Oracle easily into Excel (especially 2013+) with Power Query. You may need to download some drivers from the Oracle website, but after that, your process will be easy.

1) Find out if you need to download PowerQuery for your version of Excel

2) Try: New Query --> From Database --> From Oracle Database

3) Download required drivers (if needed) for Oracle

Enter your server details and credentials and this will set up the connection for you. If you don't like connecting this method, you can set up an ODBC data-source on your PC and perform the same steps but step 2 would look different...

2) New Query --> From Other Sources --> From ODBC

4) Research some about PowerQuery and PowerPivot.

If you take the time to set this up, your life will become a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you for this idea, I downloaded and installed Power Query but it could only load 1 048 576 rows (although it shows in the right panel that it loaded 5 million rows), if i find out how to display all 5 million then I will do a vlookup, do you think this is the best way ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Assuming this is your "data table" and you have some other values with characteristics in a "lookup table" you should not use VLOOKUP! When you are using the data model in Excel because the new way you manage large data sets in Excel is not with millions of formulae but by building relationships between tables. If you go to "Manage Data Model" in Excel you should find your 5MM data table. Now you need to add your lookup table and create a relationship. Once you do that, there is no need for making a "combination table," you can create amazing pivot tables exploiting this relationship.